# Vue3 script setup without all the imports from vue

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I find it very repetitive to have to import vue things like:
`import { ref, computed } from 'vue'`
In the script setup section.

Would it be a bad practice to, let's say assign vue to a special character, like `$` and then use it to access these like
`let drawer = $.ref(null);`

If so what would be the reasoning behind?

Comment: If you are using typescript, it will be a problem because it lacks typing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [experimental version](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/369) of vue3:

```js
// vite.config.js
export default {
  plugins: [
    vue({
      reactivityTransform: true
    })
  ]
}
```

after that there is an auto import available and you don't have to write `.value` if using a `$ref` or `$computed`.

> Because $ref() is a macro and not a runtime API, it doesn't need to be imported from vue.

Comment: Thanks. This is a solution, and I will take a look. However, I'm more curious about the reasoning. ....

Comment: After looking deeper into the experimental version, I can say that it's focused on accessing variables with `.value`. The import becomes unnecessary as it is implemented with a macro.

Comment: Just a little update: Reactivity Transform was an experimental feature, and has been removed in the latest 3.4 release. [More info here](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use unplugin-auto-import:
https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import

Example using vite.config.js:

```
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [AutoImport({imports: ['vue']})]
})
```